# file_get_contents returning different value. But that same URL is returning another value if it is run on a browser

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have an URL. When I am running that URL via browser, it is giving the expected response. But when it is called via file_get_contents, it is returning a different response.

There are a lot of parameters with the value in the Korean Language. I am not sure why it is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Also, we have used `curl`, but it was returning blank. So, curl didn't work too.

Comment: Please post you code. Are you sure you're not looking up a different path by mistake? Relative paths can sometimes different files than you're expecting

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($url) {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($content,'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}
```

Comment: We tried this one too. But if you see, you are calling the function `mb_convert_encoding` after using `file_get_contents`. So it will not make any difference.

Comment: Also, we have used `curl`, but it was returning blank. So, curl didn't work too.